# Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties, skip @Configuration if not valid

Tags: spring-boot

In a Spring Boot 1.5.13 project, I have a @Configuration object with some @NotEmpty fields:

```java
@Configuration
@Validated
public class Test {
  @NotEmpty
  private String name;
  private String optionalOne;
  private String optionalTwo;
  @NotEmpty
  private String location;
  ...
}
```

And a @ConfigurationProperties class that loads it from application.yml:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test.config")
public class TestConfig {
  @Valid
  Map<String, Test> testRecords = new HashMap<>();
  ...
}
```

There are several "Test" records in the configuration files.

Default behavior from spring is that if validation fails, like if one of the records has a missing `location`, then an error prevents the app from starting up.

I would instead like the behavior to be that the invalid record is logged and skipped, so that the app continues startup, loading only the valid records, and loading no records that are missing the `@NotEmpty` fields.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement the validation yourself without any annotations. After the beans are constructed check the constraints programatically (maybe in a @PostConstruct method) to avoid fighting with Spring.